# Error $|\hat{f}_n(x)-f(x)|$ with regressogram estimator

Tags: regression, estimation, nonparametric, error, estimators

I am learning about non parametric estimation, and more specifically about regressogram:

Let $(X_i,Y_i)_{i = 1}^n$ be a sequence of random variables in $[0,1]$ variables and $E[Y_i|X_i] = f(X_i)$. Let $I_1,\dots,I_K$ be the regular partition of the unit interval. Suppose $x\in I_k$, then
$$\hat{f}_n(x) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i1(X_i\in I_k)}{\sum_{i=1}^n1(X_i\in I_k)}.$$

I would like to know how to control the error $|\hat{f}_n(x)-f(x)|$? Is there a reference?

Comment: I think you are supposed to sum on i, not k.

Comment: my mistake, edited

Comment: What is $r(x)$?

Comment: It's certainly better to call it $\hat{f}$, it's the regressogram estimator (sorry I mixed the notations of several refs)

Comment: This is quite easy to do for non-random $X_i$ but for random $X_i$ it can be quite difficult.